# Telling if regular expression contains a single invariable segment

Tags: regex

I write a search tool which is optimized to first look for fixed phrases of characters in sentences - consider it a simple "does the sentence contain a particular sequence of characters". The result will be a set of found sentences which can be searched further in a second stage.

For this second stage I like to apply regex search for convenience. But I need to pre-select the items first at the first stage, and I cannot simply get all sentences - the API I need to use for the first stage requires me to search for a phrase of at least one matching char. So there's no way around this.

Now, the user will only enter one regex, and my software needs to first determine if it can perform the first stage search on this. If the user enters something ambiguous, I will then tell the user to change his regex.

I need the algorithm that determines all substrings I can use for the first stage search.

Here are some examples of expected results:

- **a.b** – Yes (searches for "a" or "b" first)
- **a|b** – No (there'd be two distinct first level searches necessary)
- **[ab]** – No (same problem: Not a clear target for the first stage search)
- **[ab]c** – Yes (searches for "c" first)

These are simple examples. But since regex can get quite complicated I wonder if I can construct a regex or other test that will tell me if I have a usable outcome.
I could also live with limiting the regex syntax to the more common cases if that makes the test simpler, e.g. no recursion or whatever could help.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Is there a specific programming language you intend to use to solve this issue? In .NET you can get access to the Regex parse tree through private reflection, which would get you pretty far. I have part of that code available here: http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7476#58159

Comment: You don't know the language most probably: REALbasic. Although, it's pretty close to VB, and I'm quite familiar with any procedural language (C, Pascal etc), but have a hard time with functional ones. I can also read Java (and probably C#) but do not have access to their libs in my environment. Targeted OS is OSX, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, using Haskell. The algorithm should be easily transferred to another language.

Just some boilerplate imports;

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import Data.Function
```

Here is a datatype to represent a Regex. You'll have to parse it yourself or use a library:

```
data Regex
    = Concat Regex Regex -- e.g. /ab/
    | Alt Regex Regex    -- e.g. /a|b/
    | Single Char        -- e.g. /a/
    | Star Regex         -- e.g. /a*/
    | CharClass [(Char,Char)] -- a list of ranges. for non-range (e.g. [a]) just use the same char twice
```

Here is the algorithm:

```
regexMustMatch (Single x)    = [Just x]   -- has to match the character
regexMustMatch (Alt _ _)     = [Nothing]  -- doesn't need to match one thing (you could actually check for equality here, so something like /a|a/ would work)
regexMustMatch (Star _)      = [Nothing]  -- doesn't need to match one thing 
regexMustMatch (CharClass ((a,b):[])) | a == b = [Just a] -- char class must match if it only has one character
regexMustMatch (CharClass _) = [Nothing]                  -- otherwise doesn't need to match one thing 
regexMustMatch (Concat x y)  = (regexMustMatch x) ++ (regexMustMatch y) -- must match both parts in sequence
```

Some methods to make the results usable:

```
selectAll = map (concatMap (return . fromJust)) .
            filter (isJust . head) .
            groupBy ((==) `on` isJust)

selectLongest x = case selectAll x of
        [] -> ""
        xs -> maximumBy (compare `on` length) xs
```

And some examples:

```
main = do
    -- your tests
    -- /ab/
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ (Single 'a' `Concat` Single 'b')
    -- /a|b/
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ (Single 'a' `Alt` Single 'b')
    -- /[ab]/
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ (CharClass [('a','a'),('b','b')])
    -- /[ab]c/
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ ((Single 'a' `Alt` Single 'b') `Concat` Single 'c')

    -- a few more
    -- /[a]/
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ (CharClass [('a','a')])
    -- /ab*c/
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ (Single 'a' `Concat` Star (Single 'b') `Concat` Single 'c')
    -- /s(ab*)(cd)/ - these aren't capturing parens, just grouping to test associativity
    print . selectAll . regexMustMatch $ (Single 's' `Concat` (Single 'a' `Concat` Star (Single 'b')) `Concat` (Single 'c' `Concat` Single 'd'))
```

Output:

```
["ab"]      -- /ab/
[]          -- /a|b/
[]          -- /[ab]/
["c"]       -- /[ab]c/
["a"]       -- /[a]/
["a","c"]   -- /ab*c/
["sa","cd"] -- /s(ab*)(cd)/
```

The main area where this could be improved is in the algorithm for alternation.

If we have the regex `/a*bc*|d*be*/` then `b` needs to be matched, but this won't pick that up.

**Edit**: here's an improved algorithm for alternation:

```
regexMustMatch (Alt x y)
    | x' == y' = x'
    | otherwise = start ++ [Nothing] ++ common ++ [Nothing] ++ end
    where
        x' = regexMustMatch x
        y' = regexMustMatch y
        start = map fst $ takeWhile (uncurry (==)) (zip x' y')
        end = map fst $ reverse $ takeWhile (uncurry (==)) (zip (reverse (drop (length start) x')) (reverse (drop (length start) y')))
        dropEnds = drop (length start) . reverse . drop (length end) . reverse
        common = intercalate [Nothing] $ map (map Just) (selectAll (dropEnds x') `intersect` selectAll (dropEnds y'))
```

Some more tests with the improved alternation:

```
/a*bc*|d*be*/    == b
/s(abc*|abe*)/   == sab
/s(a*bc*|d*be*)/ == s, b
/sa*b|b*/        == s
/(abc*|abe*)s/   == ab, s
/(a*bc*|d*be*)s/ == b, s
/(a*b|b*)s/      == s
/s(ab|b)e/       == s, be
/s(ba|b)e/       == sb, e
/s(b|b)e/        == sbe
/s(ac*b|ac*b)e/  == sa, be
```

Comment: Awesome. I do not really bother about the "/a*bc*|d*be*/", that's too academic for my purpose. But I wonder if "/ab+" could result in "ab", not just "a". That's be a nice optimization. I'll check your code tomorrow, it's already bedtime where I am. Hmm, and the language is hard to translate into a procedural language like C with access just to a regex lib. Gotta see what I can make of it.

Comment: This doesn't encode `+` directly, since you can translate it - `b+` is equivalent to `bb*`. If you do this, `abb*` will result in `"ab"`.